# detecting AWS dynamodb connection error in vogels or node SDK

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, vogels

I am using the npm [vogels](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vogels) package, which is built on the main [aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk) package for accessing all AWS services, including DynamoDB.

I'm trying to get good error handling when the connection cannot be made (wrong credentials, etc), but currently the vogels queries just hang indefinitely when I intentionally break my connection parameters. I don't see any connection error handling API available, but ideally I'd like to bind an `error` event handler or similar so when I cannot connect, the program does not simply hang.

Comment: hmm, so you make a call (what sort of  operation did you try?) and it didn't return an error to the callback?